# JSTL presentation problem- if statement

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to represent the columns based on the value of the fetched from an arraylist.

```
<c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
        <c:if test="${(cell != 'Read') || (cell !='Write')}" >
            <td id="access">${cell}</td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${(cell == 'Read') || (cell =='Write')}" >
            <td>${cell}</td>
        </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

I have 3 types of value coming in cell- Read, Write and Others. For Others it is going into != condition, but for Read and Write, it satisfy both the if statements. I was not able to use if-else.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the equivalent if-else statement of your code if the second IF in your code as the ELSE.

```
<c:forEach items="${row}" var="cell">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${cell ne 'Read' or cell ne 'Write'}">
            <td id="access">${cell}</td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <td>${cell}</td>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Check your conditional statement in IF. As voidnnull point out about your first IF instead of using || (or) use && (and).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using the `||` operator in the first test condition.

Use the && operator and it will work as expected.
`<c:if test="${(cell != 'Read') && (cell !='Write')}" >`

Additionally for a if-else construct using JSTL, use `<c:choose>` tag under which you can use `<c:when>` and `<c:otherwise>`. They work in a similar manner to if-else.

Example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/if.html